# BBComm Authentication Mechanism

Tags: bloomberg, blpapi

I have a .NET process that collects a bunch of rates each morning before I get in -- this does a few things:

1. Checks if bbcomm.exe is running
2. Starts bbcomm.exe if it's not running
3. Creates a Session on localhost:8194 then connects to the //blp/refdata service
4. Pull some historical and reference data points

Works great, except when it doesn't.

Sometimes the connection to Bloomberg persists after I logoff Bloomberg Desktop, even after a reboot, for several days.

Sometimes it doesn't and it won't collect rates until I logon to Bloomberg which starts the connections up right away.

Does BBComm cache my credentials? I see in bbcomm.log it initiates the connection with an SSL certificate -- is this specific to my PC? Is it generated when I logon to Bloomberg, and expires at some interval?

How does it work aside from magic?

Comment: If you have Bloomberg Anywhere, logging onto your mobile or a different PC will disconnect your bbcomm session. Otherwise it can stay up and running for a while.

Comment: Fwiw, you don't need to check `bbcomm.exe` and try to start it. Calling the `start` method of the Session object will do this for you.